# Highcharts drilldown data from mysql

Tags: mysql, highcharts

Im trying to use the drill down method for my chart similar to this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown/sand-signika%5d%5b1%5d.
But I want to drilldown my data from YEARS,MONTHS,WEEKS & DAYS. How can I execute that? Heres my code:

```
$query = "SELECT sum(product_total) as total, YEAR(`date`) as year FROM confirm_order_product GROUP BY YEAR(date) ORDER BY date";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $salestotal[] = $row['total'];
    $sdate[] = $row['year'];
}
$salesdate = json_encode($sdate, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$sales = json_encode($salestotal, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Container:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Sales Report'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: <?php echo $salesdate; ?>

      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
              },
      tooltip: {
        valuePrefix: '₱'
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data:<?php echo $sales; ?>,


}],


    });
  });
```

This only displays per year.

Comment: Could you show the content of `$sales` variable?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z2s7ek6o/

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yhbo2twu/ - click the first column to get the days.

Comment: How can I implement that using my code/data? Im kinda confuse when it comes dynamic.

Comment: You can fetch data from the server when `drilldown` event occurs using AJAX. Check this example simulating it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6grL0fsy/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown

Comment: Can you make another example? but this time using my data? I really cant figure it out, I can send you the files. This would really help me a lot for my schoolwork.